# Which software use the package sessioninstaller?

Tags: package-management

I see the package *sessioninstaller*, it doesn't mention any dependencies in the package manager, when I try to uninstall it, everything is okay.
But the description says "it allows applications to easily install additional software (e.g. extensions or Gstreamer codecs)".

I don't know if I need it, except for GStreamer. I couldn't find a list of application that calls this package. Is there somewhere roughly a list of some apps that uses it? I know it only install additional packages, but I don't know which apps use this package.

Comment: There is no list because any application can potentially be made to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sessioninstaller` package was removed from new releases of Debian in 2014 because nothing used it anymore. See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=755504

The package was removed from new releases of Ubuntu after 19.10.

Comment: Thank you, you solved this mystery.